# background-size width only

Tags: css, image, width

I have made a full screen slide show on a web page I am making, but as a entry page after they are 'done' with the slide show..I want to put a picture on top with the width expanding to full size in width after the resolution to the user. While the height is gonna be static..like 600px.

Is there a way to do this? With CSS or something? I am new to CSS and after googling for many days I havent found any decent example of what I am trying to make

I do not have any example ready of what I am trying to archieve, but hopefully someone will have a idea of what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I only has Paint here on this computer, and sorry about my arrows. http://i62.tinypic.com/29y62io.png

Comment: Do you want the image to be cropped or expanded according to the page width?

Comment: It will probably be cropped at most. I am using a 1600x600 picture, so if there is anyone with Full-HD resolution, then it will be expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a container like this

**HTML:**

```
<div id="boom">
    plop
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#boom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1600x600);
}
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/fx5jM/

Comment: Thanks :) I have tried th previous example, and it works good. Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 6):

You can set two different values in `background-size`:

```
.yourimg {
      background-image: url('yourimghere.jpg');
      background-size: 100% 600px;
}
```

Comment: ahhh right, that makes sense. The first is width and the second is height. Got it, I will try it out

Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. If you need to, you could also set `height` for the element itself. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7BG/1/)

Comment: Ok thanks. From the example there is looks like the 'picture' did fill the whole screen no matter what I set for height. But I think I get the idea. I will try it out

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the value! [This one should work](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7BG/2/)

Comment: Perfect. The test picture is looking good with the changes I make, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.backgroundImage{
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:600px;
}
```